# Media Queries, which one is the better way and why?

Tags: html, css, media-queries, responsive

I've been writing Media Queries, after all of my normal CSS styles (desktop and laptop devices). But, recently, looking at some examples and bootstraps CSS files, I notice media queries are directly followed after the css is written. This example will better illustrate my question,

```
.content {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 40px; 
    font-size: 1rem;  
    }
.something{
   background: red;
   padding:20px;
   width:800px;
}
   // The Media Queries after I write all normal CSS
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .content{
      padding:10p;
      //some style for mobile
    }
    .something{
       width:100%;
   //some style for mobile
    }
}
```

Or

```
.content {
        padding-top: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 40px; 
        font-size: 1rem;  
        }
// Media Query Directly After the CSS
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
        .content{
          padding:10p;
          //some style for mobile
        }
}
.something{
       background: red;
       padding:20px;
       width:800px;
    }
       // Media Query Directly After the CSS
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {        
    .something{
           width:100%;
       //some style for mobile
        }
    }
```

So, I'm curious, which is the correct way or the better way?

I've been doing the first way, as I don't have to repeat the media queries "@media only screen and (max-width: ..px)" everytime.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly one would prefer to group the media query versions of the CSS rules together with the non-media query versions, so they can be managed together. For example, if I write separate CSS for each component, I would usually want both media query versions and non-media query versions of the rules for that component to be in the file for that component. When I add and modify rules, I would prefer to do that in one place, rather than two or more.

If it bothers you that you have to write the media query again and again, which is a valid concern from the standpoint of maintaining your code when changing breakpoints, consider using a preprocessor such as postCSS which allows you to define aliases for media queries. For instance, [this plugin](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-custom-media) would allow you to write

```
@custom-media --small-viewport (max-width: 30em);

@media (--small-viewport) {
  /* styles for small viewport */
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the plugin link! I'll surely give it a try!

Answer (score 4):

It really depends on you. There is no "right" way to do it. It depends on how you wish to organize your stylesheets. If you have many media query rules for different viewports, then it might make more sense to do it the way you've been doing, because you're right -- it is more efficient to have sections for different media queries. The examples that you've looked at may be doing it differently to make it more easily understood to other people reading it. I think the only important thing is to try to choose a way and stick to it as much as you reasonably can. (At the same time, rules are meant to be broken occasionally.) In the long run, this will help your code be more predictable, and it'll be easier for you to understand and maintain it.

Comment: *it is more efficient to have sections for different media queries*. More efficient in what sense?

Comment: @torazaburo I just mean a shorter file length for the reason you mentioned in your answer (repeating media query blocks over and over). I agree, if you could use a preprocessor, that would make keeping the multiple-viewports-per-rule method more attractive.

Answer (score 0):

The Second option is the better way to do it.As if there occurs any change in CSS after sometime then you need to find the class for normal CSS as well as Media Queries.

In this case you just need to search for it once only.

Comment: It comes down to preference and what methodologies / CSS architectures are at play. It's not as simple as "one way is better than another".

Answer (score 0):

For the examples given it mostly boils down to a personal preference, there are pros and cons for both examples.

The first example, having a single `@media` rule adheres to the [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principles, which are considered best practise. The downside to this is that it may not be clear right away that some different styling may apply to those elements.

The second example, having `@media` rules following the initial declaration appear to make the declarations easier to follow as one immediately can see things will be different for different `@media`. Though it is not DRY.

---

I prefer the first approach, adding the `@media` rules to the stylesheet as late as possible and having multiple overrides in them.

My reasons for doing so are simple:

- it's DRY by design
- if you ever feel to need to have the media queries on `<link>`-elements you can more easily extract those into separate files
- it never stops with just one `@media` rule, there will be more and when that happens, all readability/clarity arguments in favor of the second approach (immediate overrides) lose their value as you'll get clutter.

Comment: You're misinterpreting the DRY principle, subverting it into something like "avoid duplicative typing". The definitive definition, AFAIK, is actually that "a piece of knowledge must have a single, unambiguous, authoritative representation within a system." Your proposal is actually **less** dry, because it splits the definition of the rule for `.content` across multiple files. When you read about DRY, the discussion often involves pre-processors or code generators; for instance, a schema processor which  spits out both SQL queries and program code to avoid having to change both yourself.

Comment: (continued) In this case, what corresponds to the schema processor is some mechanism for pre-defining, or aliasing, breakpoints (media query definitions) in one place, then using those definitions wherever they are needed. That's what the postCSS media plugin does, with its `--small-viewport` definition. That in turn allows you to write truly DRY code, where there is a single representation for the rule for `.content`.

Comment: (continued) If you are worried about downloading rules which are irrelevant to the user's current device size, there are other server-side mechanisms for filtering rules and downloading only the ones relevant to the current form factor; it does not need to be done at a file-by-file level.